# google maps в маркерах табы

Tags: javascript

Есть google maps карта. Работает замечательно. С кучей маркеров. В каждом маркере должны быть ОДИНАКОВЫЕ ТАБЫ. и если с тем же бутсрапа вне карты всё работает. стоит этот код занести во внутрь маркера как не работает не одна вкладка. Побывал уже и так

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click',
                (function (marker, i) 
                {
                    return function ()
                    {
                      alert("aaaa"); //алерт показывается но табы не работают
                    }
                })(marker, i));
```

Побывал даже на чистом css не работает. Перебраковывал куча плагинов с табами не работает. Как всё же инициализировать эти табы?

Comment: Я встречался с похожей проблемой , если очевидных проблем нет в виде ошибок в консоли то нужно просто контейнеру карты задать четкие размеры `<div class="item active" style='width:500px;height:500px;'>`

Comment: Проблема не в этом. В прошлом сообщении я забыл указать что при клики на вкладку в адресе появляется #tab1 #tab2 #tab3 ошибок в консоли нету

Comment: в общем вся проблема в библиотеке infoBubble отключаешь табы работаю брал и InfoWindows так же беда. Куда копать?

Answer (score 1):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, content) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('.nav-tabs a').click(function () {
                                $(this).tab('show');
                            })
                            $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show');
                        }, 500); 
})(marker, content));
```